# Switch works on double click | ROR

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, togglebutton

I am using a switch (something like toggle button) to show some data to the users. But the switch only works on double click instead of single.

Below is the code from .js file -

```
var integrations = {
    init: function() {
      $("input[type='checkbox'].integration").bootstrapSwitch();

      $("input[type='checkbox'].integration").on('switchChange.bootstrapSwitch', function(e, state) {
        $(this).siblings('.bootstrap-switch-label').click();
        var val = $("input[type='checkbox'].integration").val()
        if (val === 'true')
          $(this).prop( "checked", true);
        else
          $(this).prop( "checked", false);
      });

      this.jiraService = w.service.get('jira').init();
      this.jiraService.initEvents();

      if (w.Clipboard) {
        new w.Clipboard(".copy.tooltip-right");
      }
    }
  };
```

Does anyone know how to make it work for single click? Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone is still looking for the solution, try this one -

```
if ($(this).on(".bootstrap-switch-handle-on bootstrap-switch-success").click())
  $(this).prop( "checked", true);
else
  $(this).prop( "checked", false);
```

Changing the if condition works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check by commenting out below line, it might be possible that label is also making the switch click.

```
$(this).siblings('.bootstrap-switch-label').click();
```